# .bash_profile and scripts as symbolic links

Tags: macos, git, shell, symlink, bash

I'd like to know, if there is any problem when I set my `.bash_profile` or other configs such as `.irssi` or `.slate` as symbolic links. The thing is, I would like to git all my configs and scripts in `/usr/local/bin`(I'm on OS X), so that I have version control and a backup for them. This way, I can also use them on other machines.

I was just wondering whether anything could break, if I'm doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes as long as the symlinks are valid and the user has proper permissions to read those locations, you should not have any problem.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing breaks, that's exactly how people put their dotfiles under version control